# Can't get GPG Key for teamviewer repo

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

I installed teamviewer with the .deb file from the website and it seems, as if it automatically added a ppa. Unfortunately it didn't add the GPG Key so its always throwing an error at me:

```
root@Kubuntu-Aerobook:~# apt update
OK:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-3/ubuntu groovy InRelease
OK:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                               
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                               
Holen:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease [96,2 kB]                                                         
Holen:5 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease [11,0 kB]                                         
OK:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                              
OK:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                   
OK:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Fehl:5 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
  Die folgenden Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden, weil ihr öffentlicher Schlüssel nicht verfügbar ist: NO_PUBKEY C5E224500C1289C0
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
W: GPG-Fehler: http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease: Die folgenden Signaturen konnten nicht überprüft werden, weil ihr öffentlicher Schlüssel nicht verfügbar ist: NO_PUBKEY C5E224500C1289C0
E: Das Depot »http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease« ist nicht signiert.
N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
```

I tried this comand (thats why im root and didn't used `sudo`):

```
wget -O - https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/signature/TeamViewer2017.asc | apt-key add -
```

and also:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
```

but nothing worked.
I tried different versions of the .deb file and also tried to set it to developer repo, but always the same problem.

hope you can help :-)

Comment: Hey Darius Eberl! It looks like you're running as root which is not a safe thing to do. Which Ubuntu version are you using? I suggest you to paste the commands' output in English since many users in Ask Ubuntu are familiar with English. (Use the [edit] feature to edit your question.)

Comment: Hey, i will post in english, if you tell me how. Additionally (because i knew you would tell me not to work as root) i wrote in my question, why i did work as root.

Comment: You can follow the instructions mentioned in this webiste (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html.en) to change the language in Ubuntu. After changing the language and restarting the session, execute the command and now the output must be in English. Copy the output and paste it in the question (Use the [edit] feature to edit your question).

Comment: I just solved a similar problem: Teamviewer broke "apt-get update" because the installer didnt install its GPG key (on arm64 Debian Buster chroot). Teamviewer's apt configuration looks for the key in /usr/share/keyrings/teamviewer-keyring.gpg - not /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d, its important to put it the dearmored key in the right place

Answer (score 4):

To get the latest GPG key for TeamViewer's repo, their .asc key file needs to be converted before passing it to apt-key.

```
curl -L https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/signature/TeamViewer2017.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: You will also need to run `# cp /etc/apt/trusted.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` after that as `apt-key` is deprecated and subsequent `apt update`s will throw warnings otherwise.